# JavaFX Application Thread выполняется бесконечно?

Tags: многопоточность, javafx

Мне вдруг стало интересно. Вот **GUI**, например **JavaFX**, запускается в своём отдельном потоке. При этом, если создаю поток для своих целей в приложении, то поток умирает, когда выполняет то, что от него требовалось. Однако в случае с **GUI** события нажатия кнопка и клика мышью можно ждать долго и при этом **JavaFX Application Thread** вроде как работает, ведь за событием последует реакция. Выходит, что **JavaFX Application Thread** выполняется в бесконечном цикле?
Как это реализовано?

Comment: исходный код JavaFX доступен для исследования. задайте конкретный вопрос,

Comment: Конкретизирую. Как сделано так, что поток GUI постонянно работает? Метод run находится в бесконечном цикле? (вроде while(true){})

Comment: @SergeyLotvin да

Comment: если да, то как это реализовано? бесконечный цикл?

Comment: если вы хотите узнать как это реализовано в коде JavaFX, то просто посмотрите в исходный код. если же вопрос про другое, то уточните, что именно вас интересует.

Comment: к моему стыду, я не смог найти, где посмотреть исходный код. ткните носом.
а вообще, ноги вопроса растут от задачи. мне надо сделать опрос тегов по **OPC** в отдельном потоке. я сделал подключение, сделал поток и там в методе `run()` реализовал опрос. метод  `run()` своего потока я сделал бесконечным циклом и вот думаю - а правильно ли это? есть ли более оптимальный способ?